# Android How to achieve two screens,two activities，and they are independent

Tags: android, screens

I am a novice at Android, now, I need write a android app:two screens also shows two activities, boradcast advertising on the big screen, the small screen can be operated, and they are independent of each other.When people operate the small screen, the advertising will still play. I found the presentation class in the android 4.4 API 20,with it I can realize the two screens display different contents, I also refer to the Google demo, but Because the presentation depends on the specific activity, when the small screen operated, then intent to another activity, before playing advertising presentation disappeared. Then I came up with a method: The application only have one activity, the small screen using many fragments, but because the following screen operation is very complicated, it would be more trouble with fragment, my friends advised me not to use fragment, but I can't find other methods,who can help me?thank you very much(My English is poor,sorry)

Comment: Fragments aren't that hard, see my code I made as clean as possible on Fragments here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57543/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default . The only key difference is that you need to add the Support Library (which in ADT is just right click on project -> android tools -> add support library), and extend from `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: @ITbaker use fragments http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a detailed tutorial of Fragment. In my opinion, you'll be able to achieve what you want, only by using fragments :

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html